# Performing authentication using NAS-Port attribute

Tags: freeradius

I have an environment where we are intending to authenticate IPoE CPE based on the service ID passed on by the carrier rather than username/password. In our case the BNG routers will receive DHCP requests with option 82 set with the service ID and act as a DHCP/RADIUS gateway. I'm hoping to map option 82 to the NAS-Port attribute and authenticate based on that. Has anyone here done something similar? If so can you share the methods you used and your experience.